# Program printing wrong output

Tags: c

Why is the following code printing `!notreblo!` instead of `!notrebloH`? Where is the `!` coming from? I am trying to write a program that reverses an array and I am using the `main` function to test the `rev_string` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
   char s[11] = "Holberton!";

   printf("%s\n", s);
   rev_string(s);
   printf("%s\n", s);
   return (0);
}

void rev_string(char *s)
{
    char new[500];
    int count, newcount;

    count = 0, newcount = 0;

    while (*(s + count) != '\0')
    {
            *(new + count) = *(s + count);
            count++;
    }

    count--;

    while (count > 0)
    {
            *(s + newcount) = *(new + count);
            count--;
            newcount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `*(ptr + index)` is the same as `ptr[index]`. Lots of people prefer the 2nd format :-)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In addition to the answers you've gotten: Your `rev_string` function is fragile. If you give it a string that is longer than 499 characters, it will go out of bounds. If you look at it more closely, you can do the reversal _without_ using the temporary `new` array by reversing the string in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `while` does not copy the first character, because the last character copied is at index 1. The condition tells it so: `count > 0`.

Change it to `count >= 0`.

(+1 for the famous "one-off" error. If I got 1 cent each time, I'll be a rich person.)

Answer (score 4):

Notice your second `while` condition: `while (count > 0)`. You aren't including your last character - e.g. if `count == 3` (3 characters to reverse), you will only iterate twice - and your third character will not be written. You need to change the condition to `while (count >= 0)`.

---

As a bonus, the function you are implementing is better known as [strrev](http://manpages.org/strrev/3) - and it can be implemented without an additional buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should change your second while condition to `while (count >= 0)`